# Get User Role in entity framework using join query in asp.net core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, join

I have 4 tables called Users, Roles, Photos and UserRelationships. Users & Roles tables are identity server tables. I want to return user list with their role names. I can get other details, but I'm stuck when getting Role name.

Here are the screenshots of tables created by myself

Photos:

[image: Click here to view image]

UserRelationships:

[image: Click here to view image]

This is the code I tried

```
var relations = await (from relation in _context.UserRelationships
                                   where (relation.RelatingUserId == id || relation.RelatedUserId == id)
                                    && (relation.Status == UserRelationShipStatus.Active)
                                    && (relation.Type != UserRelationshipType.Blocked)

                                   select new
                                   {
                                       RelationId = relation.Id,
                                       User = relation.RelatedUserId == id ? (from usr in _context.Users
                                                                              join photo in _context.Photos on usr.Id equals photo.UserId
                                                                              where usr.Id == relation.RelatingUserId && photo.IsMain == true
                                                                              select new
                                                                              {
                                                                                  UserId = usr.Id,
                                                                                  UserName = usr.UserName,
                                                                                  PhotoUrl = photo.Url,
                                                                                  Role = ?
                                                                              })
                                                       : (from usr in _context.Users
                                                          join photo in _context.Photos on usr.Id equals photo.UserId
                                                          where usr.Id == relation.RelatedUserId && photo.IsMain == true
                                                          select new
                                                          {
                                                              UserId = usr.Id,
                                                              UserName = usr.UserName,
                                                              PhotoUrl = photo.Url,
                                                              Role = ?
                                                          })

                                   }
                                  ).ToListAsync();
```

What I'm doing here is in my UserRelationships table contains two fields called RelatingUserId & RelatedUserId. It means relationships send user and received user. If the passing UserId equal either one of these fields then I want to get that user details. I want to know is when getting user role how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not retrieve data in Linq query. Try to return the result with ViewModel instead of anonymous type. And then add Roles to the result by retrieving user role.

1.Create ViewModel

```
public class UserRelationshipsViewModel
{
    public string RelationId { get; set; }
    public UserViewModel User { get; set; }

}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PhotoUrl {get; set;}

    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

2.Return data with ViewModel

```
var relations = await (from relation in _context.UserRelationships
                               ...
                               select new UserRelationshipsViewModel
                               {
                                   RelationId = relation.Id,
                                   User = relation.RelatedUserId == id ? (from usr in _context.Users
                                                                          join photo in _context.Photos on usr.Id equals photo.UserId
                                                                          where usr.Id == relation.RelatingUserId && photo.IsMain == true
                                                                          select new UserViewModel
                                                                          {
                                                                              UserId = usr.Id,
                                                                              UserName = usr.UserName,
                                                                              PhotoUrl = photo.Url,

                                                                          })
                                                   : (from usr in _context.Users
                                                      join photo in _context.Photos on usr.Id equals photo.UserId
                                                      where usr.Id == relation.RelatedUserId && photo.IsMain == true
                                                      select new UserViewModel
                                                      {
                                                          UserId = usr.Id,
                                                          UserName = usr.UserName,
                                                          PhotoUrl = photo.Url,

                                                      })

                               }
                              ).ToListAsync();
```

3.Add Roles to data.

```
 foreach (var r in relations)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(r.User.UserId);
            var Roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            r.User.Roles = Roles;
        }
```

Update:

It will lead to bad performance when there are thousands of users.I tried to join UserRoles table to get roles.

```
              (from usr in _context.Users

                    join ur in _context.UserRoles on usr.Id equals ur.UserId into bt
                    join photo in _context.Photos on usr.Id equals photo.UserId
                    where usr.Id == relation.RelatingUserId && photo.IsMain == true
                    select new
                    {

                        Roles = (from x in bt
                                join r in _context.Roles on x.RoleId equals r.Id
                                select new
                                {
                                    r.Name
                                }
                                ).ToList()

                    })
```

Comment: ,thank you very much for your reply,please tell me,If I do this as multiple processes,I meant first get data set and after merge roles to them,is it a good habit?
I'm talking about performance of this project.This web site may has thousand of users

Comment: It does not a good habit.I updated my answer to join UserRoles table to get roles of user for default identity.

Comment: ,thanks alot.Now I can return user roles.thanks again ah :)

Comment: If you have a time,can you please help me to solve this issue.I have another problem in entity framework.I opened question.Here is it's link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57505867/how-to-data-fetch-using-entity-framework-in-dotnet-core