# How to Data Fetch using Entity Framework in dotnet core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have a table called "UserAnswers".below screenshot contains table data
[image]

I want to get data by surveyId and group by CreatedBy column.

for an example
There is a user called "amara@gmail.com".this user contains 4 records for a SurveyId.
I want to get this like below

```
Answers : [
            {"2"},
            {"1","0","1","1"},
            {"1","2","4","3"},
            {"Blue"}]
```

But my code returns this array for every rows.I meant duplicate records returning.

Here is my code

```
 var qstns = await (from uans in _context.UserAnswers
                                       where uans.SurveyId == id
                                       select new UserAnswersReturnDto
                                       {
                                           UserEmail = uans.CreatedBy,
                                           Qustns = (from ans in _context.UserAnswers
                                                      where ans.CreatedBy == uans.CreatedBy 
                                                      select new UserAnswersSet
                                           {
                                               QNo = ans.QNo,
                                               Ansrs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ans.Answers) ? "[]" : ans.Answers)
                                           }).ToArray() 

                                       }).ToListAsync();
```

So how to solve this issue.I opened many questions for this problem,but no one answered.Please help me.Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually group your data before returning:

I used LINQ Lambda notation, but it should be quite easy to translate back to query if you're so inclined:

```
var qstns = _context.UserAnswers.Where(uans => uans.SurveyId == id)
                                .GroupBy(uans => uans.CreatedBy)
                                .Select(grans => new UserAnswersReturnDto {
                                    UserEmail = grans.Key,
                                    Qustions = grans.Select(ans => new UserAnswersSet() {
                                        QNo = ans.QNo,
                                        Ansrs = ans.Answers
                                    }).ToList()
                                } ).ToList();
```

I didn't have time to double-check this, but I hope it serves as a guide to help you solve your issue!

Comment: Wow..You are a genius akseli.Actually I opened many questions regarding to this.But no one answered me.This is the correct answer.thanks in advanced :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no group by statement in your linq query.

Comment: I sad, I can't understand how to write my code with group by statement. how ever thanks for your reply.Now I got my answer :)